# PlayFramework 2.0.2 multiple parameters in routes

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I cant seem to get multiple parameters to work if i add one parameter everything is fine as soon as i add a second parameter i always get a

```
No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.
```

Can anyone else confirm that you can add a second param to a request using play 2.0.2?
(using java)

My url is as simple as this

```
http://localhost:9000/account/foruser?username=somethig&amp;create=0
```

and the routes

```
GET     /account/foruser
controllers.user.UserController.foruser(username:String, create:Boolean )
```

Comment: I am also experiencing the problem with multiple query string parameters. The documentation does not exclude this case so it looks like a bug that the DynamicForm approach is a work-around for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should put some more attention on the routes [docs and samples](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaRouting)

In general if you're using named params with `&name=value` you don't need to specify them in the routes files.  Instead use DynamicForm in the Java to access them.

Route file is used for matching `unnamed` parts of the link with controler's action and params. So your link should look like:

```
http://localhost:9000/account/foruser/something/0
```

and route (of course this need to be placed in one line in routes file:

```
GET     /account/foruser/:username/:create
   controllers.user.UserController.foruser(username: String, create: Integer )
```

Note that was some bug reports on using the Boolean type in the route, so it's just safer to use some numeric type instead.

Comment: I tried to extract data out of a url using a form, but I couldn't get it to work. I used the regular the myform.get() method to extracts data in an instance of a class. Could you give us an example of how to do it please ?

Comment: @Moebius give me sample of URL first

Answer (score 1):

@biesior I am getting the same problem using 2.0.4 with two types of parameters

File routes:

```
GET /v2/object/all/data/:from/:until/:all           controllers.ObjectController.getAllData(from: String, until: String , all: Boolean, username: String ?= null, password: String ?=null)
```

File controller:

```
public static Result getAllData(
            @PathParam("from") String from,
            @PathParam("until") String until,
            @PathParam("all") Boolean all,
            @QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password)
```

After doing several tests I finally solved the problem. You should use "boolean" instead of Boolean, so "getAllData" transforms to:

```
public static Result getAllData(
            @PathParam("from") String from,
            @PathParam("until") String until,
            @PathParam("all") boolean all,
            @QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password)
```

Comment: Here are more [problems with boolean and play 2.0](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/5yCi6AvDnyo/discussion) (solved in 2.1), so I recommend to use integer instead

Answer (score 1):

A quick example :

The correct url corresponding to this route :

```
GET     /user/update:action/:id controllers.myFunction(action: String, id: String)
```

Is the url :

```
myWebsite.com/user/update$action=update/$id=a@a.fr
```

Note that :

- each one of the url params begin by a $
- No & or ? in the url !
- The / between :id and :action must be there. Play redirect to the correct webpage without it, but it is nescessary if you want to have the correct value (ie action => '$action=update' and id => '$id=a@a.fr') transmitted to your function
- When you have an error, java display an error with the regex to apply to each route.